# load jquery tabs on dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i'm trying to load tabs in a modal window, and it's not calling the JS `.tabs()` method im wondering what i'm doing wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/uMTC7/24/

I don't know if there is a conflict between the bootstrap `tab()` method, but i suppose it could be a possibility.

```
$('.launcher').on('click',function() {

var domhtml ='<div id="tabs">'+
'<ul>'+
'<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>'+
'<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>'+
'<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>'+
'</ul>'+
'<div id="tabs-1"><p>Tab 1 Stuff</p></div>'+
'<div id="tabs-2">'+
'<p>Tab 2 Stuff</p></div>'+
'<div id="tabs-3"><p>Tab 3 Stuff</p></div></div>';


               BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Draggable Dialog',
            message: domhtml,
            draggable: true,
                        buttons: [{
                label: 'Cloze',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(dialog){
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }]
        });    
    //this does not load:
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

});
```

Comment: Did you tried just on jsfiddle or weren't tabs loaded even in your html-js files? I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uMTC7/28/ , I added a button which calls `tabs()`. When I click that button on modal, it loads the tabs.

Comment: how do i do it on open?

Comment: This is a similar case when it happened me before, I needed an after show event which bootstrap3 doesn't have. I finally decided to use a different modal plugin on some of my pages called _SimpleModal_. It has `onShow` callback which you can call `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();`.

Comment: i am using simplemodal ~_~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script would start executing as soon as your document is ready, binding all the events to the corresponding elements. Since your div#tabs is created only on click of the button, and is not available prior to that, none of the events would get bound to it.

Hence, you have to pass your elements with all the handlers attached. You can do that either as shown below, or you can bind them within your click function and pass the final variable to the *message* option. Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uMTC7/34/)

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Draggable Dialog',
            message: function(dialog){
                var $content = $(domhtml);
                $($content).tabs();
                return $content;
            },
            draggable: true,
                        buttons: [{
                label: 'Cloze',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(dialog){
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }]
        });
```